Disable window overlay (24.04)
Just what it says on the tin: I do not want automated all-window tiling (i.e. the behavior bound to the SUPER key—specifically on release of the SUPER key—where all windows become small and simultaneously visible across the entire screen) under any circumstance. How to achieve this?
I am using 24.04, and Gnome on X.
EDIT: Apparently the behavior I am describing is called 'overlay', not 'tilling'

I believe you are mentioning the "Overview" in Ubuntu which shows up when we press the Super key. We might need to disable the Super key from launching the overview using gsettings.

Open a terminal.

Run the following command to disable the Super key from opening the overview:
gsettings set org.gnome.mutter overlay-key ''



This command clears the action assigned to the Super key to show the overview.
You can revert the above process using the below command, just in case:
gsettings reset org.gnome.mutter overlay-key


BLESS YOU! It is such a small thing, but has been driving me nuts!

Using the Ubuntu Tiling Assistant extension.
sudo apt install gnome-shell-extension-manager
activate it with extension-manager
Under the Installed tab disable Ubuntu Tiling Assistant.

Or more simply...
gnome-extensions disable tiling-assistant@ubuntu.com

I hope this is of some help

-1 (1) Ubuntu Tiling Assistant is already disabled and this does not prevent the behavior I described. (2) Your second command does not disable tiling as described in my question.
